# Image Download with URL params

Tags: android, image, download

i am using ImageDownloader.java file t download/cache images from server but its unable to download the images when i am trying to download images from resize API i.e. http://www.xxxxx.com/wp-content/image2png.php?src=/2013/11/GAP.jpg&mode=fixed&form=jpg

ImageDownloader.java working perfectly on URL which ending with .jpg and .png extensions.

**ImageDownloaded.java**

public class ImageDownloader {

```
public ImageDownloader(String _FileLocation) {
    super();
    this._FileLocation = _FileLocation;
}

public static final int _FULLDOWNLOAD = 0;
public static final int _FULLDOWNLOAD_WITHOUTCACHE = 1;
public static final int _SCALEDDOWNLOAD = 2;

private SaveFileToHardDrive imageByteDownloader = new SaveFileToHardDrive();
private String _FileLocation = "";

public enum Mode {
    NO_ASYNC_TASK, NO_DOWNLOADED_DRAWABLE, CORRECT
}

private Mode mode = Mode.CORRECT;

public void download(int downloadType, String url, ImageView imageView, View progressBar) {
    resetPurgeTimer();

    if(!url.contains("http")){
        url = "http:" + url;
    }

    ImageData bitmap = getBitmapFromCache(url);

    if (bitmap == null || bitmap.getBitMap() == null) {
        forceDownload(downloadType, url, imageView, progressBar);
    } else {
        cancelPotentialDownload(url, imageView);

        try {
            imageView.setImageURI(bitmap.getBitMap());
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (progressBar != null)
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}


private void forceDownload(int downloadType, String url, ImageView imageView, View progressBar) {
    // State sanity: url is guaranteed to never be null in DownloadedDrawable and cache keys.
    if (url == null) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        if (progressBar != null)
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return;
    }

    if (cancelPotentialDownload(url, imageView)) {
        switch (mode) {


        case CORRECT:
            try {
                BitmapDownloaderTask task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView, progressBar);
                DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = new DownloadedDrawable(task);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(downloadedDrawable);
                // imageView.setMinimumHeight(156);
                Object[] obj = { url, downloadType };
                // task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, obj);
                task.execute(obj);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}


private static boolean cancelPotentialDownload(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);

    if (bitmapDownloaderTask != null) {
        String bitmapUrl = bitmapDownloaderTask.url;
        if ((bitmapUrl == null) || (!bitmapUrl.equals(url))) {
            bitmapDownloaderTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            // The same URL is already being downloaded.
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


private static BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
    if (imageView != null) {
        Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        if (drawable instanceof DownloadedDrawable) {
            DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = (DownloadedDrawable) drawable;
            return downloadedDrawable.getBitmapDownloaderTask();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

String downloadBitmap(String url, int downloadType) {
    try {
        // url = new Utility().stripWrongContent(url, " ", "%20");
        String imageByte = imageByteDownloader.fetchActualImagePath(url, _FileLocation, SaveFileToHardDrive._RegulerImagesDierctory);
        if (imageByte != null && !imageByte.contains("file://null")) {
            return imageByte;
        }
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        clearCache();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}


static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        super(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
        while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
            long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
            if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                int b = read();
                if (b < 0) {
                    break; // we reached EOF
                } else {
                    bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                }
            }
            totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
        }
        return totalBytesSkipped;
    }
}


class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, ImageData> {
    private String url;
    private int downloadType = 0;
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    protected WeakReference<View> progRef;

    public BitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView, View progressBar) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        progRef = new WeakReference<View>(progressBar);
    }

    /**
     * Actual download method.
     */
    @Override
    protected ImageData doInBackground(Object... params) {
        url = (String) params[0];
        downloadType = (Integer) params[1];
        ImageData imData = new ImageData();
        imData.setBitMap(downloadBitmap(url, downloadType));
        imData.setDownloadType(downloadType);
        return imData;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ImageData bitmap) {
        View prog = progRef.get();
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
            if (prog != null)
                prog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        addBitmapToCache(url, bitmap);

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
            // Change bitmap only if this process is still associated with it
            // Or if we don't use any bitmap to task association (NO_DOWNLOADED_DRAWABLE mode)
            if ((this == bitmapDownloaderTask) || (mode != Mode.CORRECT)) {

                try {
                    if (bitmap.getBitMap() != null)
                        imageView.setImageURI(bitmap.getBitMap());
                    else
                        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (prog != null)
                    prog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
    }
}


static class DownloadedDrawable extends ColorDrawable {
    private final WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask> bitmapDownloaderTaskReference;

    public DownloadedDrawable(BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask) {
        super(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        bitmapDownloaderTaskReference = new WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask>(bitmapDownloaderTask);
    }

    public BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask() {
        return bitmapDownloaderTaskReference.get();
    }
}

public void setMode(Mode mode) {
    this.mode = mode;
    clearCache();
}



private static final int HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY = 15;
private static final int DELAY_BEFORE_PURGE = 10 * 1000; // in milliseconds

// Hard cache, with a fixed maximum capacity and a life duration
private final HashMap<String, ImageData> sHardBitmapCache = new LinkedHashMap<String, ImageData>(HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY / 2, 0.75f, true) {
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(LinkedHashMap.Entry<String, ImageData> eldest) {
        if (size() > HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY) {
            // Entries push-out of hard reference cache are transferred to soft reference cache
            sSoftBitmapCache.put(eldest.getKey(), new SoftReference<ImageData>(eldest.getValue()));
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
};

// Soft cache for bitmaps kicked out of hard cache
private final static ConcurrentHashMap<String, SoftReference<ImageData>> sSoftBitmapCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, SoftReference<ImageData>>(HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY / 2);

private final Handler purgeHandler = new Handler();

private final Runnable purger = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        clearCache();
    }
};


private void addBitmapToCache(String url, ImageData bitmap) {
    if (bitmap != null) {
        synchronized (sHardBitmapCache) {
            sHardBitmapCache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
    }
}


private ImageData getBitmapFromCache(String url) {
    try {
        // First try the hard reference cache
        synchronized (sHardBitmapCache) {
            final ImageData bitmap = sHardBitmapCache.get(url);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                // Bitmap found in hard cache
                // Move element to first position, so that it is removed last
                sHardBitmapCache.remove(url);
                sHardBitmapCache.put(url, bitmap);
                return bitmap;
            }
        }

        // Then try the soft reference cache
        SoftReference<ImageData> bitmapReference = sSoftBitmapCache.get(url);
        if (bitmapReference != null) {
            final ImageData bitmap = bitmapReference.get();
            if (bitmap != null) {
                // Bitmap found in soft cache
                return bitmap;
            } else {
                // Soft reference has been Garbage Collected
                sSoftBitmapCache.remove(url);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}


public void clearCache() {
    try {
        sHardBitmapCache.clear();
        sSoftBitmapCache.clear();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void resetPurgeTimer() {
    purgeHandler.removeCallbacks(purger);
    purgeHandler.postDelayed(purger, DELAY_BEFORE_PURGE);
}
```

}